# How to write a function that collects a specific list of observations from a time series data frame

Tags: r, function, time-series

In the data set created below, assume I randomly picked up 20 flat rocks. Each of these rocks were assigned a unique ID number. I measured the concentration of 7 substances (Copper,Iron,Carbon,Lead,Mg,CaCO, and Zinc) across the surface of the longest axis of each rock. Distance is recorded in mm, and therefore is a function of each rocks length. Note that not all Rocks are of the same length. Location is a grouping variable that describes where the Rock was picked up.

```
ID <- data.frame(ID=rep(c(12,122,242,329,595,130,145,245,654,878), each = 200))
ID2 <- data.frame(ID=rep(c(863,425,24,92,75,3,200,300,40,500), each = 300))
RockID<-data.frame(RockID = c(unlist(ID), unlist(ID2)))
Location <- rep(c("Alpha","Beta","Charlie","Delta","Echo"), each = 1000)
a <- rep(c(1:200),times = 10)
b <- rep(c(1:300), times = 10)
Time <- data.frame(Time = c(unlist(a), unlist(b)))
set.seed(1)
Copper <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 5)
Iron <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 10)
Carbon <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 1)
Lead <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 4)
Mg <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 6)
CaCO <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 2)
Zinc <- rnorm(5000, mean = 0, sd = 3)
data <-cbind(RockID, Location, Time,Copper,Iron,Carbon,Lead,Mg,CaCO,Zinc)
data$ID <- as.factor(data$RockID)
```

I want to create a new data frame that contains the following information: 
1. The first observation and the last observation for each individual
2. The average of the first 3 observations and last 3 observations for each individual
3. The same as step 2. for the first and last 5, 7, and 10 observations
I want the new data frame to be set up like this:

```r
ID  FirstPt First3  First5  First7  First10 LastPt  Last3  Last5  Last7  Last10 
12   …       …        …      …         …     …       …      …      …     … 
122 
242
329
595
130
145
245
654
878
863
425
ect...
```

How would I write a function to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a function to calculate average of first and last `n` values. Use `pivot_longer` to get data in long format, `group_by` each `RockID` and substance and calculate the mean.

```
library(dplyr) 

average_of_first_n_values <- function(value, x) mean(head(value, x))
average_of_last_n_values <-  function(value, x) mean(tail(value, x))

data %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = Copper:Zinc) %>%
  group_by(RockID, name) %>%
  summarise(first_obs = first(value), 
            last_obs = last(value), 
            first_3_avg = average_of_first_n_values(value, 3), 
            first_5_avg = average_of_first_n_values(value, 5), 
            first_7_avg = average_of_first_n_values(value, 7), 
            first_10_avg = average_of_first_n_values(value, 10), 
            last_3_avg = average_of_last_n_values(value, 3), 
            last_5_avg = average_of_last_n_values(value, 5), 
            last_7_avg = average_of_last_n_values(value, 7), 
            last_10_avg = average_of_last_n_values(value, 10))
```

Comment: this works perfectly! Could you explain the use of "name" in the `group_by()` function. I see what it is doing, but I don't understand why it is doing it. Also out of curiosity, if I wanted to round the numbers in the new columns to 2 decimal places, how would I incorporate `round()` in this function?

Comment: I can do this by saving that in an object called `PtData`, and using `PtData[,3:12]<-round(PtData[,3:12],2)` in another line. I was just wondering if there was a way to do this within the function you wrote

Comment: @Ryan you can change the function to `average_of_first_n_values <- function(value, x) round(mean(head(value, x)), 2)` and same for the other one which will return you rounded values. As far as usage of `name` os concerned if you run `data %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = Copper:Zinc) ` part of the code it gives you a column called `name` which has all the substances like Copper, Zinc etc and since we want unique values for each rock and substance in there, we use `group_by(RockID, name)`.

Comment: awesome I see how that works now thanks! Another question of interest (I hope it's okay to ask these questions in the comments): say I wanted to keep the grouping column `Location` in the output. if I add `,Location` after `,name` in the `group_by()` call, it doesn't appear to change the functionality of the code. Am I correct? What if I want to do the same thing, but have `Location`  as the first column, and maintain the alphabetical order in that column?

Comment: just add `Location` in `group_by` (`group_by(Location, RockID, name)`) and if you want to sort the rows alphabetically use `arrange(Location)` at the end.